# How to Handle Subscribe in component.spec.ts Jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am still learn about Jasmine x Karma and I got stuck when I need to create unit testing for function which have .subscribe()
In **component.ts** the code look like this

```
 loadListDownloadRequestGroup() {
this.noItem = false;
this.listDownloadService.getDownloadRequestGroup(
  this.offsetPage,
  this.getGroupId,
  this.setOrder,
  this.keywordSend
).subscribe(resp => {
  const getResp: DownloadModel[] = [];
  if (resp.items.length) {
    resp.items.forEach(item => {
      const listArr: DownloadModel = {};
      listArr.id = item.id;
      listArr.queryId = item.queryId;
      listArr.createdAt = item.createdAt;
      listArr.filename = item.filename;
      listArr.queryName = item.queryName;
      listArr.widgetName = item.widgetName;
      listArr.type = item.type;
      listArr.labelName = item.labelName;
      listArr.createdByName = item.createdByName;
      listArr.expiredAt = item.expiredAt;
      listArr.status = item.status;
      listArr.group = item.group;
      listArr.groupId = item.group ? item.group.id : null;
      listArr.groupName = item.group ? item.group.name : '-';
      getResp.push(listArr);
    });
  } else {
    this.noItem = true;
    this.emptyDataText = (this.isInitGetlistData == false) ? 
      'There is no data to display' : 
      'There is no search result. Please input different keyword';
  }
  this.dataSourceDT = new MatTableDataSource(getResp);
  this.dataSourceDT.sort = this.sort;
  this.totalData = resp.total;
  this.totalOffset = Math.ceil(this.totalData / 5);
}, (error) => {
  if (error.graphQLErrors[0].statusCode === 403) {
    this.route.navigate(['unauthorized']);
  }
});
```

}

on **.spec.ts** I write like this but it's doesn't effect the code coverage

it('loadListDownloadRequestGroup', () => {

```
// const getAllDownload =  spyOn(listDownloadService, 'getAllDownload').and.callThrough();

const event = { items: [{
  id: 2,
  queryId: 2,
  createdAt: '2019-09-09',
  filename: 'test',
  queryName: 'test lagi',
  widgetName: 'test widget',
  type: 'test type',
  labelName: 'test labelName',
  createdByName: 'test createdByName',
  expiredAt: '2019-08-08',
  status: 'published',
  group: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'test group'
  }
}] };

component.loadListDownloadRequestGroup();
// expect(getAllDownload).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(component.isInitGetlistData).toBeFalsy();
expect(component.noItem).toBeFalsy();
expect(event.items.length).toEqual(1);
```

})

Answer (score 1):

you can use a "done" callback

- detailed explanation here: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-test-observables-a00038c7faad

for example

```
it('loadListDownloadRequestGroup', done => {
  const loadList = component.loadListDownloadRequestGroup();
  loadList.subscribe(list => {
   expect(component.isInitGetlistData).toBeFalsy();
   expect(component.noItem).toBeFalsy();
   expect(event.items.length).toEqual(1);
   done();
  });
});
```